How do I fix GitLab's Web IDE after update from 17.2.9 to 17.5.1?
After upgrading GitLab-ee, Docker, Omnibus from 17.2.9 to 17.3.6 and finally to 17.5.1 when on a file in my repo in GitLab and I click on Edit -> Open in Web IDE (vscode_web_ide) I am forwarded he 500 error page.
This behavior was not present in 17.2.9 or previous versions I have had installed.  I posted this problem as an issue with GitLab, but am not getting a response.
How do I fix this?
Logs:
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-exporter/current <==
2024-10-29_05:50:26.69914 ::1 - - [29/Oct/2024:05:50:26 UTC] "GET /sidekiq HTTP/1.1" 200 579
2024-10-29_05:50:26.69917 - -> /sidekiq

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError ():
encryptor (3.0.0) lib/encryptor.rb:98:in final' encryptor (3.0.0) lib/encryptor.rb:98:in crypt'
encryptor (3.0.0) lib/encryptor.rb:49:in decrypt' vendor/gems/attr_encrypted/lib/attr_encrypted.rb:244:in attr_decrypt'
vendor/gems/attr_encrypted/lib/attr_encrypted.rb:333:in attr_decrypt' vendor/gems/attr_encrypted/lib/attr_encrypted.rb:163:in block (2 levels) in attr_encrypted'
activemodel (7.0.8.4) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in block in validate' activemodel (7.0.8.4) lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in each'
activemodel (7.0.8.4) lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in validate' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in block in make_lambda'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in block (2 levels) in halting' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:687:in block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:686:in catch' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:686:in block in default_terminator'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in block in halting' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in block in invoke_before'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in each' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in invoke_before'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:106:in run_callbacks' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:929:in _run_validate_callbacks'
activemodel (7.0.8.4) lib/active_model/validations.rb:406:in run_validations!' activemodel (7.0.8.4) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:115:in block in run_validations!'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:107:in run_callbacks' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:929:in _run_validation_callbacks'
activemodel (7.0.8.4) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:115:in run_validations!' activemodel (7.0.8.4) lib/active_model/validations.rb:337:in valid?'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/validations.rb:68:in valid?' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/validations.rb:84:in perform_validations'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/validations.rb:53:in save!' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:302:in block in save!'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:354:in block in with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:314:in transaction'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in public_send' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in block in write_using_load_balancer'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:141:in block in read_write' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:228:in retry_with_backoff'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:130:in read_write' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in write_using_load_balancer'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:78:in transaction' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:350:in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:302:in save!' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:54:in save!'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:782:in block in update!' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:354:in block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:314:in transaction' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in public_send'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in block in write_using_load_balancer' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:141:in block in read_write'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:228:in retry_with_backoff' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:130:in read_write'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in write_using_load_balancer' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:78:in transaction'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:350:in with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:780:in update!'
lib/web_ide/default_oauth_application.rb:51:in block in ensure_oauth_application!' app/models/concerns/cross_database_modification.rb:91:in block in transaction'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in block in within_new_transaction' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in handle_interrupt'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in block in synchronize' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in handle_interrupt'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in synchronize' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in within_new_transaction'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:316:in transaction' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in public_send'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in block in write_using_load_balancer' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:141:in block in read_write'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:228:in retry_with_backoff' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:130:in read_write'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in write_using_load_balancer' lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:78:in transaction'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in transaction' lib/gitlab/database.rb:383:in block in transaction'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in block in instrument' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in instrument' lib/gitlab/database.rb:382:in transaction'
app/models/concerns/cross_database_modification.rb:82:in transaction' activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in transaction'
lib/web_ide/default_oauth_application.rb:39:in ensure_oauth_application!' app/controllers/ide_controller.rb:48:in ensure_web_ide_oauth_application!'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:400:in block in make_lambda' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:180:in block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:181:in block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in block in invoke_before' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in each'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in invoke_before' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:116:in block in run_callbacks'
lib/gitlab/ip_address_state.rb:11:in with' ee/app/controllers/ee/application_controller.rb:45:in set_current_ip_address'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in block in run_callbacks' app/controllers/application_controller.rb:484:in set_current_admin'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in block in run_callbacks' lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in with_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:475:in set_session_storage' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in block in run_callbacks'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:114:in with_locale' lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:120:in with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:466:in set_locale' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in block in run_callbacks'
marginalia (1.11.1) lib/marginalia.rb:109:in record_query_comment' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in block in run_callbacks'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:459:in set_current_context' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in block in run_callbacks'
sentry-rails (5.19.0) lib/sentry/rails/controller_transaction.rb:30:in block in sentry_around_action' sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry/hub.rb:102:in with_child_span'
sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:498:in with_child_span' sentry-rails (5.19.0) lib/sentry/rails/controller_transaction.rb:16:in sentry_around_action'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in block in run_callbacks' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in process_action' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23:in process_action'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in block in process_action' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in instrument' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in instrument'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in process_action' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in process_action'
activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in process_action' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in process'
actionview (7.0.8.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in process' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:249:in block in dispatch' lib/gitlab/middleware/action_controller_static_context.rb:23:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:249:in dispatch' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in serve' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in each' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in serve'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in call' gitlab-experiment (0.9.1) lib/gitlab/experiment/middleware.rb:19:in call'
flipper (0.26.2) lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:72:in memoized_call' flipper (0.26.2) lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:37:in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_shard_awareness_validation.rb:20:in block in call'
lib/gitlab/sidekiq_sharding/validator.rb:42:in enabled' lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_shard_awareness_validation.rb:20:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/memory_report.rb:13:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/speedscope.rb:13:in call'
lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/rack_middleware.rb:23:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in call' lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in block in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/web_transaction.rb:46:in run' lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:21:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in block in call'
lib/gitlab/database/query_analyzer.rb:83:in within' lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in call'
lib/ci/job_token/middleware.rb:11:in call' batch-loader (2.0.5) lib/batch_loader/middleware.rb:11:in call'
rack-attack (6.7.0) lib/rack/attack.rb:103:in call' apollo_upload_server (2.1.6) lib/apollo_upload_server/middleware.rb:19:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:173:in call' rack-attack (6.7.0) lib/rack/attack.rb:127:in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in block in call' warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in call' rack-cors (2.0.2) lib/rack/cors.rb:102:in call'
rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in call' rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in call'
rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in call' rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in call' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/unauthenticated_session_expiry.rb:18:in call' rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in context'
rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in call' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/strip_cookies.rb:29:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in block in call' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in call' sentry-rails (5.19.0) lib/sentry/rails/rescued_exception_interceptor.rb:12:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/path_traversal_check.rb:35:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in call' sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:30:in block (2 levels) in call'
sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry/hub.rb:258:in with_session_tracking' sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:411:in with_session_tracking'
sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:21:in block in call' sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry/hub.rb:59:in with_scope'
sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:391:in with_scope' sentry-ruby (5.19.0) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:20:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:29:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in call'
lograge (0.11.2) lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb:15:in call_app' railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in block in call'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in block in tagged' activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in tagged' railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:15:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/webhook_recursion_detection.rb:15:in call'
request_store (1.5.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in call' rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in call'
rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in call' rack-timeout (0.7.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:154:in block in call'
rack-timeout (0.7.0) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in timeout' rack-timeout (0.7.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:153:in call'
config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:11:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/compressed_json.rb:44:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/rack_multipart_tempfile_factory.rb:19:in call'
rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in call' lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_web_static.rb:20:in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:79:in call' gitlab-labkit (0.36.1) lib/labkit/middleware/rack.rb:22:in block in call'
gitlab-labkit (0.36.1) lib/labkit/context.rb:35:in with_context' gitlab-labkit (0.36.1) lib/labkit/middleware/rack.rb:21:in call'
actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in call' actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:131:in call'
railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in call' railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in public_send'
railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in method_missing' lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:13:in call'
rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:74:in block in call' rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in each'
rack (2.2.9) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in call' puma (6.4.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:272:in call'
puma (6.4.3) lib/puma/request.rb:100:in block in handle_request' puma (6.4.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:378:in with_force_shutdown'
puma (6.4.3) lib/puma/request.rb:99:in handle_request' puma (6.4.3) lib/puma/server.rb:464:in process_client'
puma (6.4.3) lib/puma/server.rb:245:in block in run' puma (6.4.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:155:in block in spawn_thread'

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
{"backend_id":"rails","content_type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","correlation_id":"01JBBD6MCDVN5E5M60A619DCB9","duration_ms":649,"host":"gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"https://gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443/REDACTED/documentation/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads","remote_addr":"REDACTED_IP:0","remote_ip":"REDACTED_IP","route":"^/-/","route_id":"dash","status":500,"system":"http","time":"2024-10-29T05:50:26Z","ttfb_ms":649,"uri":"/-/ide/project/REDACTED/documentation/edit/main/-/.gitlab-ci.yml","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0","written_bytes":1624}
==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
REDACTED_IP - - [29/Oct/2024:05:50:26 +0000] "GET /-/ide/project/REDACTED/documentation/edit/main/-/.gitlab-ci.yml HTTP/2.0" 500 1624 "https://gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443/REDACTED/documentation/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0" -

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
{"correlation_id":"01JBBD6N1KZTCQV207EN7SJB92","encoding":"","file":"/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/-/error-illustrations/error-500-lg.svg","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"Send static file","time":"2024-10-29T05:50:26Z","uri":"/-/error-illustrations/error-500-lg.svg"}
{"backend_id":"rails","content_type":"image/svg+xml","correlation_id":"01JBBD6N1KZTCQV207EN7SJB92","duration_ms":0,"host":"gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"https://gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443/-/ide/project/REDACTED/documentation/edit/main/-/.gitlab-ci.yml","remote_addr":"REDACTED_IP:0","remote_ip":"REDACTED_IP","route":"^/-/","route_id":"dash","status":200,"system":"http","time":"2024-10-29T05:50:26Z","ttfb_ms":0,"uri":"/-/error-illustrations/error-500-lg.svg","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0","written_bytes":6506}

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
REDACTED_IP - - [29/Oct/2024:05:50:26 +0000] "GET /-/error-illustrations/error-500-lg.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 6506 "https://gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443/-/ide/project/REDACTED/documentation/edit/main/-/.gitlab-ci.yml" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0" -

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-exporter/current <==
2024-10-29_05:50:26.97736 ::1 - - [29/Oct/2024:05:50:26 UTC] "GET /database HTTP/1.1" 200 2230
2024-10-29_05:50:26.97739 - -> /database

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
{"backend_id":"rails","content_type":"text/html","correlation_id":"01JBBD6N2BDGFBZE6KE7H99K00","duration_ms":135,"host":"gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"https://gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443/-/ide/project/REDACTED/documentation/edit/main/-/.gitlab-ci.yml","remote_addr":"REDACTED_IP:0","remote_ip":"REDACTED_IP","route":"","route_id":"default","status":301,"system":"http","time":"2024-10-29T05:50:27Z","ttfb_ms":135,"uri":"/favicon.ico","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0","written_bytes":192}

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
REDACTED_IP - - [29/Oct/2024:05:50:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 301 192 "https://gitlab.REDACTED.net:8443/-/ide/project/REDACTED/documentation/edit/main/-/.gitlab-ci.yml" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0" -
Rails Console:
irb(main):001:0> Feature.all.each { |feature| puts "#{feature.name}: #{feature.enabled?}" }
vscode_web_ide: true
ci_job_artifacts_backlog_work: true

=>
[#<Flipper::Feature:792080 name="vscode_web_ide", state=:on, enabled_gate_names=[:boolean], adapter=:memoizable>,
#<Flipper::Feature:792100 name="ci_job_artifacts_backlog_work", state=:on, enabled_gate_names=[:boolean], adapter=:memoizable>,
irb(main):002:0> Feature.enabled?(:vscode_web_ide)
=> true


Once i had this problem, but in admin settings, not only web ide. I was solve this problem, this process not fast, but you need to check all gitlab services by this commands:
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake gitlab:check
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake gitlab:doctor:secrets
Most common problems with database migrations after upgrade, second command will show problems with database if this problems are exists, so then you need to connect to your psql service in gitlab(if this module not a separate docker container):
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-psql -d "db_name" (most common names @gitlabhq_production)
And after this you can delete from db problem data
This actions one mounth ago was helped me with fix gitlab-ce after upgrade

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
